# How to split money in favor of your partner when the split creates a half penny (OpenOffice)

Tags: openoffice.org, openoffice-calc

I make $98.42. I have a 50% share with a partner, so they get $49.21, and I get $49.21, simple. What if, however, I make $76.33? I want to split the amount in favor of my partner by giving the half penny to them (i.e., from half of $76.33, namely $38.165), that is they get $38.17 and I get $38.16.

Here is what I am working with which causes problems when there is no fractional penny:

```
=IF(B1="me";ROUNDDOWN(A1/2;2);"") <-- first column
=IF(B1="them";A1;IF(B1="";"";ROUNDUP(A1/2;2))) <-- second column
```

For each respective `ROUNDDOWN/ROUNDUP`'s I need an `IF()` to detect if the result of `A1/2` splits equally in to two decimals (49.21 and 49.21), not three (38.165 and 38.165)

Comment: I'm thinking modulo? There may be a simpler solution...

Comment: Like, multiply by 1000 and divide by 2 and if modulo 0 then A, else B.  I guess that's the answer...

Answer (score 0):

COLUMN 3 - THE PENNY LESS PERSON

`=IF(B1="ME";IF(MOD(((A1/2)*1000);2)=0;A1/2;ROUNDDOWN(A1/2;2));"")`

COLUMN 4 - THE PENNY MORE PERSON

`=IF(B1="THEM";A1;IF(B1="";"";IF(MOD((A1/2)*1000;2)=0;A1/2;ROUNDUP(A1/2;2)))`

[image]

Row three (blank) has the formulas above in column 3 and 4 which produces blank spaces as desired.